# Adding and removing elements from Carousel control in sequence

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrapping

I have a carousel control in html and I have 10 elements(divs with text) in slider which you could say like having 10 children inside parent div and I want to check conditions and want to remove them accordingly. Here is what I did, I put all the children divs inside a main parent div and created another parent div which is blank and completely hidden now, every time I remove any child div while checking some condition I add the same child in hidden parent div before deleting it from main parent div. Similarly, before adding back a child div to main parent div I  delete the child from hidden div after adding it to the main div. Now, the problem is I want to add the removed divs in same sequence they were for e.g I removed div 3 and div 5 now the parent has div 1, div 2 , div4 and div 6 and now I want to add div 5 back in list so, that list should become div1, div2, div4 div 5 div 6 and so on... but keeping them back sequentially seems difficult. Please have a look at code and suggest me any alternative or anything you think I am doing wrong.

```
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide " data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Carousel indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <!-- Wrapper for carousel items -->
    <div id="parentDiv" class="carousel-inner">
        <div id="1" class="item active lx-carouselimage1 lx-height-600">
            <div class="lx-carouselheadertext align-center">1A better way to get the mortgage!</div>
            <div class="carouseltext align-center">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="2" class="item lx-carouselimage2 lx-height-600">
            <div class="lx-carouselheadertext align-center">2A better  way to get the mortgage!</div>
            <div class="carouseltext align-center">

            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="3" class="item lx-carouselimage3 lx-height-600">
            <div class="lx-carouselheadertext align-center">3A better  way to get the mortgage!</div>
            <div class="carouseltext align-center"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="visibility:hidden" id="HiddenparentDiv" class="carousel-inner">

    </div>

    <!-- Carousel controls -->
    <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"><img src="~/App/Images/chevron-left.png" class="lx-width-50"></span>
    </a>

    <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"><img src="~/App/Images/chevron-right.png" class="lx-width-50"></span>
    </a>


</div>
<div></div>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
Name of child element to be removed: <input id="nameOfChild" type="text" value="child2"><input type="button" value="Remove Element" onClick="var name=document.getElementById('nameOfChild').value; removeElement('parentDiv', name);">
<br><br>
For those who are lazy in typing in the actual names, we have these handy-dandy buttons:
<input type="button" value="Remove child1" onClick="removeElement('parentDiv', '1', 'HiddenparentDiv');">
<input type="button" value="Remove child2" onClick="removeElement('parentDiv', '2', 'HiddenparentDiv');">
<input type="button" value="Remove child3" onClick="removeElement('parentDiv', '3','HiddenparentDiv');">
<input type="button" value="Remove parentDiv" onClick="removeElement('parentDiv', 'parentDiv',' HiddenparentDiv');">
<input type="button" value="Add child1" onClick="addElement('parentDiv','1','HiddenparentDiv');">
<input type="button" value="Add child2" onClick="addElement('parentDiv','2','HiddenparentDiv');">
<input type="button" value="Add child3" onClick="addElement('parentDiv','3','HiddenparentDiv');">

<script>
    var child1 = document.getElementById('parentDiv').getElementById('1');
    //var myID = document.getElementById('child1');
    //var children = document.getElementById('1').childNodes;
  alert(child1);

    function GetIndex(childId)
    {
        alert("Inside GetIndex ");

        var tempID = childId - 1;
        var parent = document.getElementById('parentDiv');

        while (tempID >= 0)
        {
            var childid = '#' + tempID;
            alert($('#parentDiv').find('#1'));
            // var child = document.getElementById('parentDiv').childNodes;
            //var child = document.getElementById('childDiv');
            //  alert(child);
            //var child = document.hasChildNodes;
            //var child = document.getElementById(tempID).childNodes;
            var child = document.getElementById('parentDiv').innerHTML;
            alert(child);

            if (child != null)
            {
                alert("Inside IF ");

                break;
            }
            else
            {
                alert("Inside elSE ");

                tempID--;
            }
        }
        if (tempID < 0)
        {
            tempID = 0;
        }
        return tempID;

    }

    function test() {
        alert(document.getElementById('hiddenDiv'));
    }

    function removeElement(parentDiv, childDiv, hiddenDiv) {
        if (childDiv == parentDiv) {
            alert("The parent div cannot be removed.");
        }
        else {
            var hidden = document.getElementById(hiddenDiv);
            var child = document.getElementById(childDiv);
            var parent = document.getElementById(parentDiv);
            hidden.appendChild(child);
            parent.removeChild(child);
        }

    }


    function addElement(parentDiv, childDiv, hiddenDiv) {
        var hidden = document.getElementById(hiddenDiv);
        var child = document.getElementById(childDiv);
        var parent = document.getElementById(parentDiv);
       // var index = GetIndex(child.id);
        //alert(index);
        parent.appendChild(child.childNodes[GetIndex(child.id)]);  
        hidden.removeChild(child);
    }

    function myFunction() {
        var newItem = document.createElement("LI");
        var textnode = document.createTextNode("Water");
        newItem.appendChild(textnode);

        var list = document.getElementById("myList");
        list.insertBefore(newItem, list.childNodes[0]);
    }
</script>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When inserting back to visible div, check the children's ids of them which are already there and search for the biggest before the one you are appending, once you find it just insert the div with the jquery method `.after` and it will appear just after it.
You can also use `insertBefore` if you are not using jquery but that seems like a Bootstrap carousel so I think you've got jquery there.